# Как правильно получить дельту времени при помощи Stopwatch?

Tags: c#, .net

Правильно ли я получаю дельту времени?

Не уверен в правильности:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();

while (0x12 != msg.Value)
{
    if (User32Helpers.PeekMessage(out msg, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, PeekMessageFlags.PM_REMOVE))
    {
        User32Methods.TranslateMessage(ref msg);
        User32Methods.DispatchMessage(ref msg);
    }

    float delta = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0f;

    Graphics2D.Instance.Update(delta);
    Graphics2D.Instance.Render(delta);
    stopwatch.Restart();
}
```

Вызывает сомнение что можно еще получить значение из тиков, т.е. `ElapsedTicks` и поделить его на `TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond`, даже не смотря на то что при вызове ассерта для разных значений он проходит проверку, я все же не уверен.

```
float delta = stopwatch.ElapsedTicks / (TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond + .0f);
float delta2 = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.000f;

Debug.Assert(Math.Abs(delta2 - delta) > .000f);
```

Comment: у вас ошибка какая или что? Ну и обычно `stopwatch.Stop();` вызывают до того, как читают сколько времени прошло.

Comment: @tym32167, `Stop` вызывается, просто был отброшен для примера.

Comment: Как-то слишком сложно, Stop(), потом смотрите Elapsed

Comment: [public long ElapsedMilliseconds => return GetElapsedDateTimeTicks()/TicksPerMillisecond;](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Stopwatch.cs,124)?

Comment: Значит одно и тоже, вот оно как... Думал там есть разница, но ее нет.

Comment: TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed; TimeSpan это класс интервала метода. У него есть свойства на все случаи жизни. TotalMilliseconds например.

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко оформите в виде ответа?

Comment: @tym32167 оформите в виде ответа? :)

Comment: @PashaPash нет времени, если есть желание, оформите сами, я  сегодня зашиваюсь )